# facet_wrap with ggparcoord() from GGally

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I want to plot multiple parallel coordinate plots from one dataset. Currently I have a working solution with `split` and `l_ply` which produces 4 `ggplot2` objects. I would like to solve this with `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` to have a more compact layout and a single legend. Is this possible?

With a normal `ggplot2` object (boxplot) facet_wrap works perfectly. With the `GGally` function`ggparcoord()` I get the error `Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting`

What am I doing wrong?

```
require(GGally)
require(ggplot2)
# Example Data
x <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(40,0,1),
                var2=rnorm(40,0,1),
                var3=rnorm(40,0,1),
                type=factor(rep(c("x", "y"), length.out=40)),
                set=factor(rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each=10))
                )
# this works
p1 <- ggplot(x, aes(x=type, y=var1, group=type)) + geom_boxplot()
p1 <- p1 + facet_wrap(~ set)
p1 
# this does not work
p2 <- ggparcoord(x, columns=1:3, groupColumn=4) 
p2 <- p2 + facet_wrap(~ set)
p2
```

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use directly `facet_wrap()` with function `ggparcoord()` because this function use as data only those columns which are specified in call to this function. It can be seen by looking on data element of `p2`. There is no column named `set`.

```
 p2 <- ggparcoord(x, columns=1:3, groupColumn=4)
 head(p2$data)
  type .ID anyMissing variable       value
1    x   1      FALSE     var1  0.95473093
2    y   2      FALSE     var1 -0.05566205
3    x   3      FALSE     var1  2.57548872
4    y   4      FALSE     var1  0.14508261
5    x   5      FALSE     var1 -0.92022584
6    y   6      FALSE     var1 -0.05594902
```

To get the same type of plot with faceting, first, you need to add new column (contains just numbers corresponding to number of cases) to existing data frame and then reshape this data frame.

```
x$ID<-1:40
df.x<-melt(x,id.vars=c("set","ID","type"))
```

Then use function `ggplot()` and `geom_line()` to plot data.

```
ggplot(df.x,aes(x=variable,y=value,colour=type,group=ID))+
   geom_line()+facet_wrap(~set)
```

[image]